# How to convert datetime HH:DD:SS AM/PM to HH:DD AM/PM

Tags: asp.net, datetime, oracle10g, datetime-format, to-char

I have a gridview column, where I need to display time in format : 
3/2/2012 1:22 PM

but my Db saves as 
3/2/2012 1:22:42 PM

I want to remove seconds from this text. I can remove it using (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS) but how do i include the AM/PM from db column ?

Comment: Does your DB really store it as a string or some kind of datetime value?

Comment: I guess I got the answer for it.

to_char(MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM) serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format should be ('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM')

Answer (score 7):

If the database provides the date as a DateTime, try to set the DataFormatString property of the GridView column to match your needs. For example

```
{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}
```

prints the column like 03/01/2012 03:09 PM .